# Karate logging when using VSCode, Karate-Runner an karate.jar

Tags: visual-studio-code, logback, karate

i'm using vscode with karate runner an karate-standalone (karate.jar 0.9.6). I'm struggling to adjust karates log-settings.

I've placed logback-test.xml in several folders (along with karate.jar, with my feature-files, in src/test/resource. I also tried to add logback-test.xml to java classpath by patching *Karate Runner › Karate Jar: Command Line Args* but nothing worked so far.

Any help apreciated.

kind regards, Joachim

Comment: we are focusing on the 1.0 release so I suggest you try that now and help us replicate the problem if it is not fixed: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer the docs, setting a system property should work: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-netty#logging

```
java -jar -Dlogback.configurationFile=my-logback.xml karate.jar my-test.feature
```

But also note that we are focusing on the 1.0 release so I suggest you try that now and help us replicate the problem if it is not fixed: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide

And one more thing, try renaming the file to `logback.xml` and see if that works.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for your quick response ! 
Unfortunately i was searching at https://intuit.github.io/karate/#logging rather than https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-netty#logging :(

I had to slightly adjust your hint to get it work with VSCode extension:
Config-setting for karateRunner.karateJar.commandLineArgs must look like:

java -jar '-Dlogback.configurationFile=logback-test.xml' karate.jar com.intuit.karate.Main

I will immediately upgrade to 0.9.9.RC3 and tell if it's still working, (also will test with renamed logback-text.xml).
Best regards, Joachim

Comment: @Joachim great. I just realized that re-naming to `logback.xml` may have no effect. I think we may be able to make a change that if `logback.xml` is found on the classpath - that will work. let me know and feel free to open a PR

Comment: for me it's working with logback.xml both with 0.9.6 and 0.9.9. But with 0.9.9 an error occurs when i try to run a single scenario instead of an feature. I create an issue with details. Apart from that, 0.9.9 is working as expected!